# django.db.utils.IntegrityError while writing APITestCase for my views?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here I am writing test cases for my views but the test is failing with the following error.

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "content_type_id"
>
> violates not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (31, permission_name_1, null, perms1).

I am writing my own Role model since I needed to change the default `ManyToMany` relation of `Group` and `User` model .

```
class CreateRoleTest(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='username',password='passwprd@321',email='email@gmail.com')
        self.permission = Permission.objects.create(name='permission_name',codename='perms')
        self.client = APIClient()

    def test_create(self):
        url = reverse('roles:create_role')
        data = {'user':self.user,'permissions':[self.permission.pk],'name':'role_name'}
        response = self.client.post(url,data,format='json')
        print(response.json())
        return self.assertEqual(response.status_code,status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

class UpdateDeleteRoleTest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.client = APIClient()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='username1', password='passwprd@3211',
                                                         email='email@gmail.com1')
        self.permission = Permission.objects.create(name='permission_name_1', codename='perms1')
        self.role = Role.objects.create(name='role1',user=self.user,permissions=[self.permission.pk])

    def test_update(self):
        data = {'user':self.user,'permissions':[self.permission.pk],'name':'role_name2'}
        url = reverse('roles:update_role',kwargs={'pk':self.role.pk})
        response = self.client.put(url,data,format='json')
        print(response.json())
        return self.assertEqual(response.status_code,status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

models.py

```
class Role(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py

```
class CreateRole(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = RoleSerializer
    queryset = Role.objects.all()

class UpdateRole(UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = RoleSerializer
    queryset = Role.objects.all()

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it says it's missing values for the `content_type_id` column.
It's a column that is automatically generated by Django to keep track of your models. This line is likely to be the faulty one.

```
self.permission = Permission.objects.create(name='permission_name_1', codename='perms1')
```

According to the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#programmatically-creating-permissions), if you need to create permissions programmatically (it can be made through the admin, but that's indeed not good for testing) you should first get the accurate generated `content_type_id` first, then add that when creating the permission.

```
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Role)
self.permission = Permission.objects.create(name='permission_name_1', codename='perms1', content_type=content_type)
```

Also tests functions don't need to `return self.assertEqual(**)`. `self.assertEqual(**)` alone is enough.

Comment: thanks for the answer.It solved that issue but now it throws another error `TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use permissions.set() instead.
`

Comment: I think ididn't set the permission correctly since it is a many to many field

Comment: Thank you. The error message tells you what to do next.

Comment: `raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type User is not JSON serializable` what does that error means

Comment: it means it cannot be converted to the JSON format. You are trying to print it to JSON here ```print(response.json())```

Comment: I am very begineer to django rest and testing .Am I doing the right way or is it the right way to write simple test cases for my view ?

Answer (score 0):

Import this in your tests.py file

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
```

Adding this line after creating the user and before adding the permission to the user solved the issue

```
ContentType.objects.clear_cache()
```